# Referencing a list item in a list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get a value from a list in a list. I want to use square brackets for indexing instead of $ so that I can use variable names in a loop. However, I run into an issue. Please consider the following example:

```
# Create a list
mylist <- list(
  list("a", "b", "c"),
  c(1, 2, 3),
  5.14,
  "some_string"
)

# Add index names to main list
names(mylist) <- c(
  "another_list",
  "an_array",
  "a_float",
  "a_string"
)

# Add index names to sub list
names(mylist$another_list) <- c(
  "first",
  "second",
  "third"
)
```

For calling list items, the following works:

```
mylist$another_list$first
```

This, however, does not work:

```
mylist["another_list"]["first"]
```

Adding [[1]] fixes it:

```
mylist["another_list"][[1]]["first"]
```

- Why do I need to add the [[1]] here?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a question for StackOverflow since it is an R programming question.

In general, you access lists via the `[[]]` notation (or, if the elements are named, you can use `$`).

`["another_list"]` returns a list containing the list `list("a", "b", "c")` rather than the list itself. To see this, try `str(mylist["another_list"])`. You can see we get a sublist containing just "another_list" inside.

A few ways to access the way you are asking

```
mylist$another_list$first # You figured this one out
mylist[["another_list"]][["first"]] # EDIT: Notice both brackets are double
mylist[[1]][[1]] # Another method that doesn't use the names
```

Reference via Norm Matloff: http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/R/RProg/RProg.html#SECTION00094000000000000000

Related StackOverflow questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819539/proper-way-to-access-list-elements-in-r
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Comment: I made a correction to the second method: note it should be `mylist[["another_list"]][["first"]]`